# How do I cut a electric wire, that is still working?

Tags: safety

Must I wear some kind of gloves, are cutters with plastic cutters enough for safety.
I heard one should wear rubber boots. Are there other safety tips?

Comment: Elephant in the room: why? What are you going to do with the live ends once cut?

Comment: That really depends on how much voltage is on the wire.

Comment: You do not cut live wires. Period. Disconnect power off to the wire first. Besides, electrocution is not the only hazard. You don't want to entrust your life to RANDOM gloves, RANDOM plastic on cutters, or RANDOM rubber boots.

Comment: A question so undetailed but provocative, it almost comes across as trolling. If it's real, I've always thought this site (and any site) shouldn't get involved in giving guidance for potentially dangerous activity. VTC.

Comment: if you have to ask on the internet, then you are not qualified to perform the work

Answer (score 3):

Yes, easy:

ISOLATE THE SUPPLY

Relying on insulation when you really don’t understand is your chance for a Darwin Award.

Comment: Get somebody else to do it!